# different behavior of pathlib resolve function

Tags: python, path, absolute-path, pathlib

the task is to read values from a ini file

Im working with Pycharm which for some reasons can not find a file from a relative path

I use `pathlib.Path` `resolve` to set the absolut path

because `os.path.abspath("config_file/config.ini")` doesnt work with my windows setup

`filepath = pathlib.Path('../../myproject/config_file/config.ini').resolve()`

works on my current machine but when I run the code on another device the ini file can not be found again.

on this answer [Use resolve()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44569249/11702787)
are  some errors mentioned that could acour while using this function.
Are theese already resolved or Im just unaware of the functionality of `pathlib resolve` ?

Answer (score 1):

According to my experiment, comparing to `os.path.abspath`, `resolve()` is not that strict forward to use

Let's say you have following output for running below script, which means you are running on directory `/home/aaa`

```py
os.path.abspath("config_file/config.ini")
# /home/aaa/config_file/config.ini
```

`abspath` returns absolute path to you without checking whether `config_file/config.ini` exists or not.

However, `pathlib.Path.resolve()` is not the same. If you want an absolute path from `resolve()`, such file `/home/aaa/config_file/config.ini` must be exist. Otherwise, `resolve()` returns relative path to you.

To pin back your question, I guess your program cannot locate such config.ini in your window deployment. Try to check out the result of `os.getcwd()` You will know why it fails.

EDITED: Python in window behaves as I described. But, in linux platform, it is able to return abspath anyway.