# Bug in pathlib.resolve() on Windows?

Tags: python, pathlib

Python 3.9.5 on Windows:

```
z = r"X:\Projects\git\shared\GPUFoundation\Make\..\Src\*.metal"
import os
>>> os.path.realpath(z)
'X:\\Projects\\git\\shared\\GPUFoundation\\Src\\*.metal'
>>> os.path.normpath(z)
'X:\\Projects\\git\\shared\\GPUFoundation\\Src\\*.metal'
```

So far so good. Let's try pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path
>>> Path(z).resolve()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1205, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 206, in resolve
    s = self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'X:\\Projects\\git\\shared\\GPUFoundation\\Make\\..\\Src\\*.metal'
```

I remember running into similar issues with `resolve()` on Windows previously (in earlier version of Python), but I hoped these would get ironed out by now. Am I doing something wrong or is this really a bug in `resolve()`'s implementation?

[EDIT] This fails only if the paths actually exist on disk! (thanks @GordonAitchJay for verifying this). I have this path structure on disk, but if I do:

```
rm -r X:\Projects\git\shared\GPUFoundation\Src
```

Then it works (no error). So strange!

Comment: It works fine for me with Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32. `pathlib.Path(r"X:\Projects\git\shared\GPUFoundation\Make\..\Src\*.metal").resolve()` returns `WindowsPath('X:/Projects/git/shared/GPUFoundation/Src/*.metal')`.

Comment: No worries. I have observed the same behaviour with Python 3.9.5 when the path exists. It works fine with my Python 3.10.2 installation though. Looking on GibHub, they have made changes to pathlib.Path.resolve since v3.9.5, so just update your Python installation and you should be sweet. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/pathlib.py#L973

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44569249